# Why is it not possible to scrape some sites?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I’m currently learning how to scrape websites using Python / BeautifulSoup, and am interested to know why some pages can be scraped while others can’t.

For example:

- https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b0072l9v/episodes/player - the main
  content table can be scraped
- https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m0000q6v - the main content
  table can’t be scraped

Do some pages feature some kind of security that prevents scraping?

Comment: What do you mean they can't be scraped? Explain what the problem is. And parts of the page may be created via JS, so if that JS isn't run, the content you're trying to scrape doesn't exist yet.

Comment: "Do some pages feature some kind of security that prevents scraping?" yes.

Comment: You should look into Selenium, @Carcigenicate's comment is a great explanation

Comment: Any site can be scrapped. I could be harder, trickier or whatever, but anything can be scrapped (the last resource is to automate browser actions like the end user which always works, but it's the les efficient).

Comment: Look into [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [`Requests-html`](https://html.python-requests.org/).  The first is probably much more versatile but also more resource hungry as it fully simulates user interaction.  The second is a headless scraper with rendering capabilities for JS.  As already answered by previous comments, some content are JS driven and cannot be scraped unless rendered/created, which require simulated user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try to do in order to test a specific web page if it could be scraped or not is to run it against `scrapy shell`, then I wil view the response back `view(response)`so whatever is returned in that response can be scraped.